# Android WebView jQuery Ajax not working (other jQuery features working fine)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, webview

I am using jQuery version 3.2.1 for my Android app's WebView. Jquery is working fine for all the other interactive features such as show, hide, toggle etc; but, not doing anything while using ajax. I am calling ajax to get "jsonp" data from third-party website. It's working fine on regular web (chrome/Firefox). My JavaScript function looks like below:

```
function doLogin()
{
var mySiteUrl = "http://somethirdpartydomain.com/api/";
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: 'task=login&'+$('#loginForm').serialize(),
      jsonpCallback: 'callback',
      url: mySiteUrl+"v1/api.php",
      success: function (data) {
        // do stuff
        if(data.responseType == "success")
        {
            alert("Success !");
        }else if(data.responseType == "error")
        {
            alert("Error !");
        }else{
            alert("Application error !");
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Is there anything additional that I have to do to make jQuery ajax work on Android WebView? Thank you !

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to the problem? I have the same issue. And I can't edit the Serverside code no matter what.

Comment: I solved it. I had some other API issues on the server side. I would first recommend you to test your environment by using the exact set of code from above. Then we can further trace the issues.